# Is it possible to generate an algorithm that can solve a system of linear equations with binary variables in Python?

Tags: python, binary

I'm having trouble defining an algorithm that can solve a system of linear equations with binary variables.
Example given the following system of linear equations:

x_12 + x_18 + x_28 = 0

x_12 - x_18 - x_28 = 0

x_12 + x_13 + x_28 - x_38 = 0

-x_13 + x_14 - x_38 - x_48 = - 2

-x_14 + x_15 - x_48 - x_58 = -2

x_15 + x_16 + x_58 - x_68 = 0

Knowing that the values of x_12 = 0, x_18 = 0 and x_28 = 0, it is possible to create an algorithm that solves this system with the other variables assuming only values of 0 or 1.

```
variables = x_12,x_13,x_14,x_15,x_16,x_18,x_28,x_38,x_48,x_58,x_68

equations = (x_12 + x_18 + x_28, 
         x_12 - x_18 - x_28, 
         x_12 + x_13 + x_28 - x_38, 
         -x_13 + x_14 - x_38 - x_48 + 2,
         -x_14 + x_15 - x_48 - x_58 + 2,
         x_15 + x_16 + x_58 - x_68)



solve((equations),variables)
```

Comment: [`np.linalg.solve()` might be able to handle it](https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/05-NumPy-and-Arrays/05.08-Systems-of-Linear-Equations/)

Comment: Having trouble or just asking SO to do it for you? Please share your code and show where you are having trouble - people will be able to help solve the problems.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is the code, using Sympy

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a simple one to solve yourself

```
def check_equation(coefs,possible_solution):
    # of the form c1*A + c2*B + c2*C ... = 0
    return sum([a*b for a,b in zip(coefs,possible_solution)]) == 0

def simple_solver(coefs):
    nvars = len(coefs)
    for possible_solution in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=nvars):
        if check_equation(coefs,possible_solution):
           # this solution meets the condition
           yield possible_solution
```

to represent your earlier problem you would use coefs [1,1,1]

```
list(simple_solver(1,1,1)) # should be [[0,0,0]]
# satisfy 1*A + 1*B + 1*C = 0
list(simple_solver(1,-2,1)) # should be [[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
# satisfy 1*A + -2*B + 1*C = 0
```

you can then take this simple building block and solve the whole system

```
def system_solver(system_of_equations):
    solutions_pool = simple_solver(system_of_equations[0])        
    for next_eqn in system_of_equations[1:]:
        if(!solutions_pool)
            return None # no solutions
        solutions_pool = [possible_solution for possible_solution in solutions_pool if check_equation(next_eqn, possible_solution)]
    return solutions_pool # satisfy all constraints
```

bah i see now they are not always the same 3 .... its a bit harder but this might give you a place to start

Comment: Thanks I was trying to do it with sympy, but it really is more complex than it looks, I was wanting to find an easy way to define this constraint of binary variables